# can't read plist from resources

Tags: iphone, plist

in my resources directory i have a file called lsf.plist 
i want to load this file (dictionary) but i always get null as content of the file. i am using the following code. i've verified that the file is in the app after the build.

```
self.path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lsf" ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSLog(self.path);
self.lsf = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"%@",lsf);
```

The first log-output shows the path and the second one gives me null....
it would be great if you can help me to solve this issue!

Br,
martin

Comment: is "self.path" the same as "path" ?

Comment: yes it is... 
was just a copy paste failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is root of your plist array or dictionary?
Also you dont need to use self.
Heres an example from a project of mine:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"property" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *newDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```